# Reclaim cursor shape in operator pending mode of neovim while using vim-surround

Tags: neovim, cursor, plugin-vim-surround

I'm somewhat ashamed to admit, the main reason I chose neovim over vim was it's native feature of changing cursor shape in different modes. For example, it uses vertical-bar in insert mode, block-shape in normal mode and horizontal-bar in operator-pending mode.

Until recently, I didn't know there was a cursor shape for operator-pending mode. This was because I'm using [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround). So, I now don't get the horizontal-bar when pressing <kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>d</kbd>. Again, I'm ashamed to admit that this little thing bothers me. I peeked around in the plugin, but honestly I understand very little of it. The best solution I came up with was to remap the `cs` and `ds` keymaps to some `Leader` mappings, but that defeats the purpose of extending text objects.

So, I want to be able to see horizontal bar while I use default keymappings for vim-surround. How do I do that?

Comment: Are you sure that this is actually a neovim only feature? If you refer to the feature `'guicursor'`, this also exists in vim and this since version 5, see `:h new-5`. Just because it is 2018 and vim 5 was released 1998, this means for 20 years :-).

Comment: 'guicursor' doesn't work in terminal in case of vim-8.0. Or I might have done something wrong. Help?

Comment: I think vim's guicursor only works in gui-mode. But neovim's works in terminal also.

Comment: I am pretty sure now that you are right: `:h nvim-features`, `:h 'guicursor'` and `:h tui-cursor-shape` in neovim mention this.  I took the `gui` in `'guicursor'` literally. However, I use mainly macvim gui. On the command line I never missed it. IMHO `I'm somewhat ashamed to admit` feels right to me (LOL). I am still not convinced to make the switch. What I feel ashamed about is: I want to have scroll bars in my gui window. That is the reason why I still use macvim and not https://github.com/qvacua/vimr#vimr--neovim-refined which otherwise seems to be a decent gui where `CMD-X/C/V` work.

Comment: BTW: Would it be sensible to raise your question on the github issue tracker of vim-surround itself?

Comment: it's not an issue. As the answer below suggests, and the code itself does, it was built that way. I wanted a workaround.

Comment: Also, I prefer vim to emacs just because it's terminal uses, for lack of a better term, is better IMO.

Comment: I raised https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround/issues/272

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If vim-surround were implemented as 's' and 'S' (pseudo-)text-objects instead of operators `ds`, `dS`, `cs`, `cS` etc, this wouldn't be an issue. I don't know if there's some technical reason for this design choice, but anyway one solution would be to write your own wrapper `omap`:

```
let g:surround_no_mappings = 1
function! SurroundOp(char)
    if v:operator ==# 'd'
        return "\<plug>D" . a:char . "urround"
    elseif v:operator ==# 'c'
        return "\<plug>C" . a:char . "urround"
    elseif v:operator ==# 'y'
        return "\<plug>Y" . a:char . "urround"
    endif
    return ''
endfunction
omap <expr> s '<esc>'.SurroundOp('s')
omap <expr> S '<esc>'.SurroundOp('S')
```

I haven't tested it thoroughly but it seems like this would work.  The first `'<esc>'` serves to cancel the currently pending `s` operator and the rest is just surround's normal mode mapping.

This wouldn't work for `yss` or `ySs` (separate mapping for surrounding the current line), for that you can just use a plugin which provides a line textobject, e.g. [kana/vim-textobj-line](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-line), for example with [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/):

```
Plug 'kana/vim-textobj-line'
Plug 'kana/vim-textobj-user'
```

That way you can use `ysil` in place of `yss`.

This still doesn't cover [all the vim-surround mappings](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround/blob/597068870b8f093a8b2d11536c62ff31222ee8d0/plugin/surround.vim#L590-L608), there is still `xmap gS` and the insert mode mappings. You could copy those mappings into your `vimrc` to get them.